# Animação em JavaScript (hover) para Touch

Tags: javascript

Como eu posso fazer uma animação em JavaScript que possui CSS `hover` evento, funcionar para quando o usuário usar o touch em um mobile, por exemplo.

Meu código da animação não funciona para Touch (Mobile). Qual minha opção?

Comment: Java ou JavaScript?

Comment: Editei sua pergunta deduzindo através das informações fornecidas que não se trata de [Java](http://www.oracle.com/br/technologies/java/overview/index.html) e sim de [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript). Em caso de discordância desfaça a edição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comportamento de `mouse hover` não é um evento esperado para entradas de Touch na Web.

Como citado [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent), os eventos esperados para entradas de Touch são:

- [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent#touchstart);
- [touchend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent#touchend);
- [touchmove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent#touchmove);
- [touchcancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent#touchcancel);

Não contendo nenhuma referência a eventos de `hover` (que em tradução literal seria: "pairar sobre", que não é um recurso disponível na maior parte das tela Touch) e para outros eventos específicos de `mouse`.

> **Conclusão:** esse não é um comportamento esperado por usuarios que utilizam Touch, sendo assim se sua funcionalidade baseada no evento `mouse hover` for essencial para sua aplicação e ela tem como *target* dispositivos moveis e/ou com recursos de Touch, reveja a funcionalidade para adequa-la a esse novo cenário.

Referências e sugestões de leitura:

- [Há essa discussão a respeito a alternativas ao evento `hover` em dispositivos *touch-based* (Em Inglês)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-are-some-alternatives-to-hover-on-touch-based-devices);
- [Aqui temos um exemplo de implementação de uma solução alternativa a dispositivos *touch-based*, que apresenta uma solução alternativa a menus com submenus baseados em `hover` (Em Inglês)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38239/handling-hover-events-on-a-touch-screen);
- [Uma de minhas principais referências para afirmar "Não isso não é possível" (Em Inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4551043/2290538);

Comment: Realmente, porque se tu for parar para analisar no touch tu não tem como colocar nada em cima de um botão, por exemplo, e deixar ele la. Tu pode pressionar ele somente, e nisso entram os eventos citados na resposta do @Fernando